# nextjs get slow on route change in react 18 and redux(legacy and toolkit)

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit, next-redux-wrapper, react-18

the issue is: when we use react 18.0.0 to 18.2.0 the app takes around 7 sec on production to change the route. on development mode everything is fine.

I am facing this issue since the release of react18, We were using old school redux and face this issue but even after spending weeks to switch into redux toolkit the issue remains the same.

to run the redux on serverside we use next-redux-wrapper.
the app is hydrating so many time unnecessarily many times. I created a ticket but they said it is not from out library side.

did you face the same issue? please share any experience you have it could be super helpful.
thanks in advance

Comment: Why not downgrade the react version to previous version? I think that would be much easier if you don't have any react-18 specific future

Comment: this is what I did for a long time, time to time I give a try to see it might work fine. I prefer to keep everything up to date but in this case seems to be a difficult one. that is why I asked here, lets hope soon all the search engines get fine with client side rendering then we can do much better